# Creating 700 m x 700m grid in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid

I'd like to know how to create 700m x 700m grid array in ArcGIS.

I am a beginner at GIS.

I'd like to develop the insect distribution map.

Answer (score 1):

There are two tools for that:

- Cartography Tools/Data Driven Pages/Grid Index Feature
- Data Management Tools/Sampling/Create Fishnet

Most of the times I use the first one. However, I thinkt the second one might be the better option.

I believe the tool explains itself pretty good. But if you have further questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: @phyu as a new user be sure to take the [Tour]. The best way to say thanks here is by upvoting and/or accepting an answer.